# tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths not working on ViewdidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I need to insert row dynamically with row animation & it's working fine on button tap.
But when i implemented it on ViewDidLoad method after receive push notification then it is not working.

**Below is code :**

```
[array_messages addObject:[messageInfo valueForKey:@"message"]];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[array_messages count]-1 inSection:0];

messageFromTop=YES;

[self.tableViewMessage insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

Comment: Use `viewDidAppear` instead (timing issue)?

Comment: only - (void)viewDidLoad  is calling while receiving push notification. Any other idea?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what do push notifications have to do with view controller lifecycle?  They seem unrelated to me.

Comment: push notifications works only in ViewDidLoad

Comment: I have no idea what that means.

Comment: I tried without push notification in viewdidAppear(), viewWillAppear. it is not working any where. But on button tap it is working fine.

Comment: So it's an issue with push notifications which you don't mention in your question and haven't provided code for.

Comment: No , it is not an issue of push notification. Without push notification , it is also not working.

Comment: So why do you keep mentioning push notifications in your comments?

Comment: I mean to say that finally i need to implement with push notification but when i am testing static data without notification then also it is not working.Earlier i was working with notification so i mentioned in my comment .

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one. Its may be helpful to you

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[array_messages count]-1 inSection:0];
    messageFromTop=YES;

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableDatalist insertObject:obj atIndex:indexPath];

    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath inSection:0]]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
});
```

Comment: viewDidAppear not calling when i received push notificatios

Comment: I tried without push notification in viewdidAppear(), viewWillAppear. it is not working any where. But on button tap it is working fine.

Comment: Its happening because first you table view load.once table view loading than you can use this method

Comment: I added reload tableview, it is not working   .            [self.tableViewMessage reloadData];

        [array_messages addObject:@"hryr56yr"];
        
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[array_messages count]-1 inSection:0];
        messageFromTop=YES;
        [self.tableViewMessage insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

Comment: please call this code after 2 sec. May be its working

Comment: still not working. I am surprised why it's working on button tap.

Comment: if possible can you please share me you code. So, i can take right decision.

Answer (score 0):

use this code ViewDidLoad()

```
   [self performSelector:@selector(insertRow) withObject:nil afterDelay:4];
```

then

```
-(void)insertRow
{


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[array_messages count]-1 inSection:0];
    messageFromTop=YES;

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableDatalist insertObject:obj atIndex:indexPath];

    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath inSection:0]]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
});
}
```